# If $\alpha\colon T\to\mathbb{G}_m$ is a root, does $\alpha(t)$ range over $\mathbb{G}_m$ as $t$ ranges over $T$?

Tags: representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Suppose $G$ is a reductive group with maximal torus $T$, and $U$ is a $T$-stable subgroup. For $\alpha$ a root relative to $T$, fix an isomorphism $u_\alpha\colon\mathbb{G}_a\to U_\alpha$ from the additive group to the root subgroup. I read that if $u_\alpha(c)\in U$ for a $c\neq 0$, then $U_\alpha\subseteq U$ since $tu_\alpha(c)t^{-1}=u_\alpha(\alpha(t)c)\in U$ and $\alpha\neq 0$.

Since $U_\alpha=\operatorname{im}(u_\alpha)$, how do we know that $\alpha(t)c$, or equivalently just $\alpha(t)$, ranges over all of $\mathbb{G}_a$ as $t$ ranges over $T$? Are nontrivial characters of a torus always surjective?

Comment: What do you mean by "the root subgroup" for an arbitrary character? The root subgroups are - as the name signifies - defined for the roots of $G$ relative to $T$. But yes, non-trivial characters are surjective, as long as you work over an algebraically closed field.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Sorry, I meant for $\alpha$ simply to be a root. Why are the nontrivial characters surjective in that case?

Comment: Any character has the form $(x_1,\dots, x_n)\mapsto x_1^{k_1}\cdots x_n^{k_n}$ for suitable integers $k_1,\dots, k_n$. And since the field is algebraically closed, this is a surjective map when it is not identically $1$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Ah, ok, so as long as some $k_i\geq 1$, it boils down to every element in the field having a $k_i$th root.

Comment: There is probably an analogue for arbitrary reductive group schemes. But in the case of an algebraically closed field, any non-identity character is certainly surjdctive.